# iOS App Crashes on every device except devices connected with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

My app crashes and quit when user try to register a new account but that occurs on any device except devices deployed the app with Xcode.

All the devices are registered in the developer account and running iOS 11.4.1

Here is the register button function:

```
@IBAction func regButton(_ sender: Any) {

    usernameText = usernameTextField.text
    mobileText = mobileTextField.text
    emailText = emailTextField.text
    passwordText = passwordTextField.text
    fieldText = categoryTextField.text

    print(usernameText ?? "damn")
    print(mobileText ?? "damn")
    print(emailText ?? "damn")
    print(passwordText ?? "damn")
    print(fieldText ?? "damn")

    if(type=="Seeker")
    {
        let url1 = "http://app.alosboiya.com.sa/hourjob.asmx/insert_jobseeker?name="+usernameText!+"&phone="+mobileText!

        let url2 = "&email="+emailText!+"&password="+passwordText!+"&workex="+"companyDescText!"

        let url3 = "&category="+fieldText!+"&image="+"downloadURLGlobal!"

        let url4 = "&unpaidhour="+"string"+"&hourpaidlast30="+"string"+"&totalhourworked="+"string"+"&balance="+"string"+"&username="+usernameText!

        stringURL = url1 + url2 + url3 + url4
    }else
    {
        let url1 = "http://app.alosboiya.com.sa/hourjob.asmx/insert_company?name="+usernameText!+"&field="+fieldText!

        let url2 = "&phone="+mobileText!+"&email="+emailText!+"&password="+passwordText!+"&workex="+"companyDescText!"+"&crcopy="+"downloadURLGlobal!"+"&logo="+"string"+"&username="+usernameText!

        stringURL = url1 + url2
    }

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {

        if(checkbox.on==true)
        {

        let url = URL(string: stringURL!)
        Alamofire.request(url!).responseString {

            (response) in

            let result = response.result.value
            do {
                if(result=="True")
                {

                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Successfully", message: "Registration Done Successfully Congratulations",
                                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:
                        UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.doSomething))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



                }else
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Registration Failed", message: "Registration Failed Please Try Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }

        }

    }else
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "License Agreement", message: "Check to Agree Licence Agreement", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }else
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Network Connection", message: "Connection Error Please Try Again", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



}
```

Comment: you need validation for textfields

Comment: but that happens even when they are not empty

Comment: Try changing your Build Configuration to "Release" and then run it. Hopefully it will crash when you run via Xcode and you can debug where the issue is.

Comment: it is already "Release" and the situation is still the same

Answer (score 0):

If a user will tap the button but one or both text fields are empty then your app will crash due to forced unwraping (! mark) which you use in your code.

Example: if mobileText field will be empty then the your app will crash:

```
 let url1 = "http://app.alosboiya.com.sa/hourjob.asmx/insert_jobseeker?name="+usernameText!+"&phone="+mobileText!
```

the solution is to use guard statement

```
guard let usernameText = usernameTextField.text,
    mobileText = mobileTextField.text,
    emailText = emailTextField.text,
    passwordText = passwordTextField.text,
    fieldText = categoryTextField.text else {
return
}
```

Comment: it crashes in those devices even if the textfields are filled with data

Comment: and devices runs the app with Xcode are running successfully without any problem even if textfields are empty (the api allowing that until now at least) so the problem is not related to the data of the textfields in general

Comment: @Mero_Android which deployment method (AppStore, Adhoc, Developer) you use in case of devices on which the app crashes?

Comment: its Adhoc method

Comment: Do you have a physical access to the devices on which ad hoc apps were installed? If yes, then you can choose Developer Distribution method which adds support for the debugger and will give you access to debug console when device is connected to a computer with debugger (Xcode)